# MySQL Query to INSERT IF doesn't exist

Tags: mysql, insert

I need a little bit of help with a quick script I'm working on.  I have 3 columns {name,page1,page2}.  I want to insert a new row if and only if there is no duplicate row there.  I want it to check only id and page1 for duplicates.

**For Example**

Row 1:    1, 3, 5

Row 2:    1, 2, 5

Row 3:    2, 2, 5

BUT NOT

Row 4:    1, 3, 10

Sorry if this is a little confusing.

Thanks in advance!

EDIT:  I do want to also update page2 to +1 if the same ID already exists.  -Thanks

Comment: Is `id` a primary key? If so, a duplicate `id` cannot be inserted. If you need to include more columns into the *uniqueness*, use a unique constraint

Comment: id is not a primary key.  Honestly, I should probably rename it to something else like `name` or something.  But no, there can be multiple rows with the same `name` / `id`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try this code.

```
$id =$_POST['id'];
$page_1 =$_POST['page1'];
$page_2 = $_POST['page2'];

$query = 'mysql_query(select * from table_name where id='.$id.' and page1 = '.$page.'');
$result = mysql_num_rows($query);

if($result == 0){
     // enter your insert query
}
else{
echo 'row is already exit';
}
```

Comment: Works perfectly.  Not sure why I didn't think of it.

Answer (score 0):

```
INSERT INTO `table_name`(`page1`)
SELECT page1
FROM (SELECT page1 AS page) x
WHERE NOT EXISTS(SELECT page1 FROM `table_name` WHERE `page1` = $value)
```

Try this

Comment: Sorry about not clarifying.  If ID already exists, I want to do `page2 = page2 + 1`

Comment: @user1834218, did you actually try to solve it? Your comment looks to me as if you consider SO a free solution service.

Comment: Then set the id field as auto increment to avoid duplicate id field

Comment: @Devolus I spent hours last night with this and another piece of code I couldn't figure out.  And every time I post of SO and someone goes out of their way to help me and solve my solution, I buy them coffee.